# I have divided 2 column in sql lite and received a output. However, the decimals are too long and I want only 2 decimals. How do I get that?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Below is the query which I have used.  I need the result only 2 decimals not more than that.

:sum(CAST(CASE When t.issue_resolved like 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 END AS Float) * 100 /
count(t.issue_resolved) AS finalscore

t.issue_resolved (1 column)

2022-03-19  80.97826086956522 - (I want this to be only decimals)

Comment: google convert function

Answer (score 0):

You can use round function

```sql
round(sum(CAST(CASE When t.issue_resolved like 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 END AS Float) * 100 / count(t.issue_resolved),2) AS finalScore
```